# How to set description for my Custom Control to show in ToolBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

I want to add a text that tells the designer what my control is into my custom control when it is in design time. Like VS default controls in here:

[image]

I have tried `///summary` but it didn't work for me. How can it be done?

Comment: I've deleted my answer (using ToolBoxItem) as I couldn't get it to work this morning.

Comment: @overslacked In windows forms I haven't seen assigning description using `ToolBoxItem`, maybe it's possible, but using `Description` attribute, is the way that Microsoft used for providing description for standard controls.

Comment: @RezaAghaei what you wrote does seem to be correct (example http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/BackgroundWorker.cs,85d60b0d93a826fa; SRDescription is a descendant of DescriptionAttribute) however, I could not get your example to work for me either.

Comment: @overslacked If you add the control to toolbox using dll or vsix package it will show the description. But if you have your control.cs in your current project t doesn't show the tooltip when automatically adds your control to your application components tab in toolbox.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can decorate your class with [`Description`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8) attribute. Then when you add the control to toolbox using `Choose Items ...` or using a `vsix` package, the description will be shown as a tooltip for  your control:

```
[Description("Some Description")]
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
}
```

Comment: Ok, It works for dll and vsix packages. But if the class is added directly to the project it didn't work for me. Does it work for just two types of dll and vsix. What is for cs files?

Comment: @AliTor If you add the control to toolbox using dll or vsix package it will show the description. But if you have your control.cs in your current project t doesn't show the tooltip when automatically adds your control to your application components tab in toolbox.

Comment: Thank you again for the info @RezaAghaei  :)