# How do I add help text that will displayed for my windows form control in the visual studio toolbox?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, user-controls, windows-forms-designer, toolbox

If I hover on a control in the designer tool box in visual studio, I get some helpful text about the control.

[image]

But for my own controls, I only get:

[image]

The first part is obvious assembly information.  But where does the descriptive text come from?  I was assuming it was some sort of attribute, but I haven't found it yet.  I tried adding an XML comment to my class but that had no effect.  Does anyone know where the designer is getting the control description?

Comment: It seems you are looking for this post: [How to set an explainer text or Description for my custom Control for Windows Forms ToolBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36145714/3110834)

Comment: I closed the question as an exact duplicate. Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to add the Control's info by customizing the [Assembly Attributes](https://blog.codinghorror.com/custom-assemblyinfo-attributes/).

Though, didn't tested yet. You can add the Control's description in your `AssemblyInfo.cs` class.

Try adding some detail about your Control here:

```
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Add some Description about your control")]
```

Though, I am sure of the fact that the [AssemblyDescriptionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblydescriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) class returns a string containing the assembly description.

```
public AssemblyDescriptionAttribute(string description);

// Summary:
//     Gets assembly description information.
//
// Returns:
//     A string containing the assembly description.
public string Description { get; }
```

If you are able to see the description displayed after you've added to the `ToolBox` and hovering over it then please let me know.

Comment: @Rakito Yes, but there's many more than one control in the assembly?

Comment: @DarrelLee so is it working for you? Not sure about if you have more than one control in the assembly.

Comment: An assembly can contain more than 1 control and `AssemblyDescription` will not show in toolbox. Instead `[Description("Some description")]` attribute of control will be shown in toolbox. Also if your control is derived from an standard control like `Button` or `ComboBox` which the base class has `Description` attribute, the description of base class will be shown.

Comment: If you add the control to toolbox using dll or vsix package it will show the description. But if you have your control.cs in your current project t doesn't show the tooltip when automatically adds your control to your application components tab in toolbox.

Comment: You may fing this post useful: [How to set an explainer text or Description for my custom Control for Windows Forms ToolBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36145714/3110834) It seems to be an exact duplicate.

Comment: I've added the Description attribute to several of my controls but the results are not consistent.   I see the description for some of my controls, but not all.  I've tried rebuilding and resetting the toolbox, but I'm still seeing inconsistent results.  Sometime my descriptions are visible.  Sometime they are not (and the default text is displayed).   What am I missing?